# passing PHP string to JavaScript: unterminated string literal

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am assigning PHP var to my javascript var and sending to PHP file through 
ajax-jQuery, but my php variable contains newline chars which 
i have replaced with `<br>`

```
e.g.            $values1 = 'abc<br>pqr<br>xyz';  $values2 = 'xyz<br>lmn';
javascript -    var data = 'val1=<?php echo $values; ?>&val2=<?php echo $values2; ?>';
```

and then ajax script to post data to PHP file

but when i print this data on console it is giving me error- SyntaxError: unterminated string literal.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26688/maharashtrian-code-worriars

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19827/casual-marathi-chat

Comment: @Bart yes of course i will, how can i help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code:

```
var data = 'val1=<?php echo $values1; ?>&val2=<?php echo $values2; ?>';
```

Will give Javascript syntax error if one or more of your PHP variables `$values1` OR `$values2` contain single quote `'` in them.

Make sure your PHP variable don't contain single quotes in them by replacing all single quotes to something else otherwise use double quotes `"` to create JS var like this:

```
var data = "val1=<?php echo $values1; ?>&val2=<?php echo $values2; ?>";
```

Provided PHP variables don't contain double quotes.

Comment: i dont have issue with ajax data post to php, but even though when i try to print on console e.g. console.log('<?php echo $values1; ?>') it is giving error

Comment: You need to print it like this: `console.log("<?php echo $values1; ?>")` actually.

Comment: sorry, my mistake here,i am already using console.log('<?php echo $values1; ?>'), still same error

Comment: Can you print it like this: `console.log("<?php echo $values1; ?>");` note I am using `"` intead of `'`

Comment: Hmm then I guess you may have newline characters in `$values1` try this to print: `console.log("<?php echo str_replace('\n', '', $values1); ?>");`

Comment: first i m doing this $values1 = str_replace("<br />","<br>",nl2br($_POST['vals'])); then i m using $values1 in javascript

Comment: OK inside your PHP code can you do `var_dump ($values1);` and paste the output in your question above.

Comment: when my $values= "OO<br>OOO<br>OO",then it is displaying string (17) with OO then "newline" OOO then "newline" then OO -FOR var_dump($values1)

Comment: And you're viewing this output in shell or browser? If inside shell then this is indeed the cause of the problem since your string contains new line characters.

Comment: yes , i m viewing this in browser, and ofcourse my string contains new line as it is printing output with newlines on browser

Comment: In your browser even `<br>` will be printed as newline but it doesn't mean your string has new lines. Can you copy/paste var_dump output from shell window.

Comment: ,i m new to it, i dont know how to use shell window.

Comment: Hmm that makes it little difficult. Can you reproduce the problem here  on http://codepad.org/ (select Language as PHP) and run your code to see the output.

Comment: anubhava, thanks for your help and sharing views, i solved this problem, the problem was , the php var was containing "newlines" that i removed and replaced with <br> when i was pulling data from texarea, then i passed it to PHP var $values to next page.

Comment: Yup that's precisely I have been saying that you variable might have new lines in it. If you want you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo, that might cause an error:

```
// --------------------------------v
var data = 'val1=<?php echo $values1; ?>&val2=<?php echo $values2; ?>';
```

Then, I suggest you to use object as `data` parameter for Ajax request:

```
var data = {
    val1: '<?php echo $values1; ?>',
    val2: '<?php echo $values2; ?>'
};
```

Also it is better to escape single quotes `'` in both `$values1` and `$values2` variables.

Comment: thanks Vision , but i dont think its typo, coz it is working if i remove <br>.

Comment: i dont have issue with ajax data post to php, but even though when i try to print on console e.g. console.log('<?php echo $values1; ?>') it is giving error

Comment: You should surround the value with quotes: `console.log('<?php echo $values1; ?>')`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake here,i am already using console.log('<?php echo $values1; ?>'), still same error

Comment: Try to add slashes: `console.log('<?php echo addslashes($values1); ?>');`.

Comment: first i m doing this $values1 = str_replace("<br />","<br>",nl2br($_POST['vals'])); then i m using $values1 in javascript

Answer (score -1):

Try using `<br />` instead of `<br>`. Just guessing here, no testing.